# Crystal Reports Nuget 13.0.4001 generates an log4net error

Tags: crystal-reports, nuget-package

Our Visual studio project is a 64-bit website which requires the crystal reports runtime installed. We would like to include nuget packages to avoid installing the runtime.

I installed the CrystalReports.Engine nuget and 16 nuget/references are also applied including log4net v1.2.10. The project files reference "Include="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821". This is a pretty old version of the log4net.

When I run our website and try to generate a report, I get the exception "Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040...". It appears that the libraries are looking for the 32-bit version of log4net.

The nuget packages include 13.0.30.3805, not the latest 13.0.32 libraries. After doing some searching on-line, I am concerned that these nugets are not SAP generated nugets.

This leads me to a few questions:

1. Are these SAP Crystal Reports nugets?
2. How do they distinguish between 32-bit and 64-bit projects?
3. Why are these nugets not using the latest version of the libraries.
4. How do I resolve this error? (everything I have tried, doesn't fix the problem)

Comment: FYI, for those that may run into the same problems, SAP responded with:

"Don't use the Nuget packaging, Not officially supported, get SP 32 from here:

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

See my Blog on upgrading your projects:

https://blogs.sap.com/2020/10/30/upgrading-a-visual-studio-2008-2019-.net-project-with-the-latest-cr-.net-sdk-packages/"